# Ajax запрос в php

Tags: ajax, javascript

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что не так я делаю?

action.js

```
xmlh=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlh.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xmlh.readyState==4 && xmlh.status==200) {

    }

}
xmlh.open('GET','first.php?a=22',true);

xmlh.send();
```

first.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>site</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body >

    <script type="text/javascript" src="action.js"></script>
    <?php
    $a=$_REQUEST["a"];
    ?>
    </body>

</html>
```

Хочу просто вывести переменную, которую передал.

Comment: `echo` надо как минимум сделать. Как максимум - у вас весь документ передастся по аяксу, от этого надо избавляться.

Comment: сервер не видит переменной 'a'

Comment: вам надо правильно оформить first.php. Если в браузере вы откроете страницу `first.php?a=22`, то вы должны увидеть (в коде страницы) только два символа - `22`, добейтесь этого. как только сревер у вас будет работать верно переходите к javascript'у. по поводу javascript'а смотрите свой предыдущий вопрос-клон.

Comment: если честно, я ничего не понял, что я должен поменять. Если бы я знал почему оно не работает так как я делаю, я бы все сделал сам.
Я же задал GET запрос, передал переменную, почему она в php в массиве GET неоприделенна?

Comment: @hil400k при прямом запросе никакой `a` не будет. При описанном аякс-запросе - будет.

Answer (score -1):

Решение на jquery:

```
function startAJAXstep3() {
    //Берет с поля номеров содержимое        
    var str = $("#exs5").html(str);
    //Посылает в фаил step1_r.php содержимое бока номеров и вставляет в поле (#exmpls пример)  
    $.getJSON("step2_r.php?param1=" + str, function (json) {
        $.each(json.runners, function () {
            info = this['roots'];
            $('#step2-exmpls').append(info);
        });
    });
}
```

Осталось лишь подставить ваши переменные

Comment: без jquery надо